# Is there a fast algorithm for determinant of matrix filled with variables?

Tags: algorithm, polynomials, determinants

I am desperately searching for a polynomial time algorithm, that computes the determinant of a symbolic (n x n) matrix.

The problem is, that each entry of the upper triangular half of the matrix consists of a different variable (e.g. x_1, x_2, ...).

On the diagonal, each entry is a polynomial that consists of the negative sum of up to (n-1) of these variables (e.g. (- x_1 - x_2 - x_3), (- x_3 - x_2), ...).

However it is always a symmetric matrix, so the entries are the same if you mirror them along the diagonal. Maybe this property helps with the runtime?

I have already considered the LU-Decomposition algorithm, but I am afraid it only works for purely numerical matrices, or am I wrong?

Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Hello, stackoverflow might not be the right place to post questions not directly related to programming. Please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Виктор The problem is, on math.stackexchange I have once asked a similar question relating to an algorithm and I have been sent to stackoverflow...

Comment: LU (not LUP) decomposition works fine symbolically.  Every cell contains a rational function, and the set of rational functions is closed over all the required operations ( *, /, +, -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MattTimmermans comment answers the question:

"LU (not LUP) decomposition works fine symbolically. Every cell contains a rational function, and the set of rational functions is closed over all the required operations ( *, /, +, -)"

This seems to mean that I can use the LU decomposition algorithm as is, but whenever the LU decomposition algorithm uses one of these operators, this operator has to be implemented for polynomials as a subfunction.

Thanks a lot!